Basic circuit question: unexpectedly small voltage across capacitor
I have this simple circuit to time an input to a 555.  The idea is when the switch is open, the cap should charge quickly to 9v through the transistor.  When the switch is closed, the transistor disconnects the cap from the voltage source and the cap discharges in a few milliseconds.  This all works as intended when simulated in falstad.com.  But on the breadboard, the cap only ever charges to 2.7v.  This happens whether the 555 (connected to the "out" line) is connected to this circuit or not.
I assumed the problem is something I don't know about transistors (which is a lot), but when I remove the transistor from the circuit (which ought to only slow down the cap charging), the voltage across the cap drops to 35mV.  (All that with the switch open.)  Any idea what I'm doing wrong?  Thanks!


You need to include a picture of your setup, and more details about how you connected everything. If all you need is a delay and not a linear voltage ramp up, you don't need a transistor; a plain RC combination will achieve that.

Sounds like something was loading your capacitor, maybe on the output, like the discharge pin of the 555?

What did you use to measure the voltage?

I wonder why did you want to include a transistor in the first place if all you need is timing from your circuit.

"The idea is when the switch is open, the cap should charge quickly to
9v through the transistor.   When the switch is closed, the transistor
disconnects the cap from the voltage source and the cap discharges in
a few milliseconds"

What you want to do can be achieved with a mere diode, as I have done in the schematic below: R1 defines the charge time, while R2 defines the discharge time.

simulate this circuit – Schematic created using CircuitLab

Oh, of course.  Thank you!

@SamWilson If my answer is useful, please give it an upvote. If it is acceptable as an answer, please also click on the "checkmark" next to my answer to mark as "accepted answer". These votes don't cost you anything, while they show appreciation for the answer, as well as marking your question as answered so that it doesn't linger on as "unanswered question". And if someone gives you a better answer later on, you can click on the checkmark again to "un-accept" the answer and go on to "accept" another answer. Thank you.

Sure thing.  Thanks again, Edin.

@SamWilson You're welcome.

It will charge in about 30us to 8 volts and change, but the transistor requires 0.7V Vbe to turn on so the final 0.7V or so will be much slower.
When the switch is closed (conducting), ideally it would discharge through the 200k resistor with a time constant of 6ms, however when the switch is first closed after the capacitor has charged there is a low impedance path through the Vbe junction if the 9V is above the breakdown voltage (rated voltage for common transistors is -5V and actual breakdown is typically a bit less than 9V). This could permanently damage the transistor. You could add a diode in series with the base but that would double the 0.7V voltage mentioned in my first paragraph.
Not sure what you are trying to do, but that is what the circuit you have should do on the bench.

Would that explain the mere 2.7V on the capacitor, and then 27mV when transistor is removed; a damaged transistor? It's likely he made a wrong connection somewhere in the practical circuit.

@EdinFifić  I shouldn't care to speculate. Multiple things appear to be wrong.

You're right, and the questioner hasn't given us any helpful details about his setup. I have provided a better circuit for him in my answer, replacing the transistor with a diode.

I'm sure the transient path through the Vbe junction would have been an issue eventually, but as Edin points out, I never got that far!  I'm fairly certain the problem was a combination of incorrect wiring on the breadboard and a bad capacitor, as the problem disappeared when I rebuilt the circuit (as I told Edin below).  Good point about the Vbe turn-on voltage.  I was forgetting about that.
